# Read the cell value

Tags: python, openpyxl

When I use the simple example of the documentation web:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename= 'fileroute.xlsm' )
sheet_ranges = wb['Export_PM']
print((sheet_ranges['B5'].value))
```

the script provide me the reference to another cell in a different worksheet.

```
=Calculo_PM!AK20
```

How can I obtaint the value not the 'link' or reference to the cell where the value is obtained ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried: `print((sheet_ranges['B5'].internal_value))`?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation and you'll see there is a `data_only` option when loading workbooks.